# Importância da TAG em perguntas duplicadas

Tags: debate

Me surgiu um dúvida de como agir em determinada situação.

Uma mesma pergunta pode ter respostas diferentes variando de acordo com a liguagem ou banco de dados etc..

Quando existe uma mesma pergunta já respondida porém com uma `TAG` diferente, devo considerá-la duplicada?

Exemplo:
Imagine uma pergunta igual para *SQLServer* e *MySql*, essas perguntas poderão ter respostas diferentes e nem sempre as respostas de uma se aplicarão as duas perguntas, logo se jogarmos como duplicata pode ser que o *AP* fique sem a resposta que precisa.

Comment: Depende do contexto, algum caso em específico que você queira trazer para debate aqui?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depende. Tem que ver o contexto. Tem que analisar o conteúdo e ver se de fato as respostas na original podem ser aplicadas na nova para ser considerada duplicata.

Claro que pode ser que algum detalhes desimportante deve ser desconsiderado. Mas pode ser que existam especificidades importantes entre uma linguagem e outra, apesar do conceito ser o mesmo.

Em alguns casos é uma aplicação daquilo de forma mais específica, aí provavelmente não seria duplicata nem na mesma linguagem.

Tem muitos casos que a *tag* da pergunta quase é desnecessária, a pergunta é mais sobre o conceito.

Não acho que dê para colocarmos regras fixa.